# Angular-Datatable server side ajax was not loaded when initial page access, if user refresh ajax was loaded and data got displayed

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-datatables

In Angular-Datatable server side ajax was not loaded when initial page access, if user refresh or manually enter the url in browser ajax was loaded and data got displayed. **no error in console**

I tried Change detection mechanism and setTimeout too. no luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.